# style.css not working in Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a child theme for my Wordpress theme (Alpine). I have created a style.css and functions.php file.

My style.css contains the following code:

```html
  /*
 Theme Name:   Alpine Child
 Theme URI:    http://yourwebsite.com/alpine-child/
 Description:  My first child theme, based on Alpine
 Author:       Daniel Pataki
 Author URI:   http://danielpataki.com
 Template:     Alpine
 Version:      1.0.0
 Tags: one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, fluid-layout, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, post-formats, rtl-langu$
 Text Domain: Alpine-child
*
```

My functions.php contains the following code:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function namescript_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
              get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
              array('parent-style')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'namescript_scripts_scripts' );

?>
```

When I make changes to the parent style.css file the changes are implemented but this does not happen when I make changes to the style.css in the child theme.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your callback name in **add_action()**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
/**
* Enqueue scripts and styles.
*/
function namescript_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
          get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
          array('parent-style')
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'namescript_scripts' );

?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work either. I have now taken the code from the WP Codex and implemented the following:

Comment: <?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>